# how to search in multi tables with using ormlite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

i have app in android i'm using ormlite library
the database contain 5 tables
i need using searchview to quick search for any thing in this 5 tables
and view the search in listview

I have no idea about the search using ormlite

I need a better solution can be used

Comment: you need better solution? better than what? take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an Idea -

you can create QueryBuilder for each table and join them. Then use

```
queryBuilderObject.where().eq(<your searching column>, <value>).query();
```

to retrive the values. Refer [this](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html)